# mapping from another component Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I have created an array data for (title,desc,images,etc...) from one component and want to mapping in another component:

```
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
          {data.map((pizza, i) => ( 
            <>
               <Image src={pizza.imgSrc} key={i} alt="" width="500" height="500" />
            <h1 className={styles.title}>{pizza.title}</h1>
            <span className={styles.price}>{pizza.price}</span>
            <p className={styles.desc}>
          {pizza.desc}
        </p>
        </>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
```

my container CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 22%;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

It is rendering only flex-direction: column, I want to render 'row' but nothing happen.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you asking how to use flex-direction?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I don't see `flex-direction: row` in `.container`. And I would recommend you to create a wrapper instead of empty tag, because your `key={i}` won't work on `<Image />` (you can set you key only on top component)

Comment: By default is 'row' , I tried with wrapper and it worked :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the width of the container is so small, It just 22% and your image has size 500x500. You can try
`width: 100%`
or
`width: 100vw`

Comment: I tried but won't work. anyway thank you